# Score results according to provided phrase

Tags: solr

Let us say that a user enters the search phrase "world peace". However, let us also say the index contains a both document with the title "will we ever get world peace" and a document with the title "world peace, where are you?".

Now, is there a way to give documents starting with "world peace" a bigger boost than other documents? In other words, i would like matches where the title starts with the phrase to be boosted. Is that possible to achieve with Solr?

Comment: this is not sorting. you should rename the title to 'score results according to provided phrase' or so.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO this is already internally done by the [lucene scoring](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/scoring.html) but I'm not sure. Nevertheless you can tweak it. Read on [here (sweet spot)](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/package-summary.html#changingSimilarity) and [here](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html).

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to achieve something close to what you want by applying a charFilter.  It affects the input string before tokenization.  In the example below, the charFilter will prepend AAAA to the beginning of the field to which its applied.  You might then be able to add AAAA to your query to force Solr to favor phases matching the beginning of the title.  More info about this approach and other Solr tips can be found here:

http://robotlibrarian.billdueber.com/tag/stupid_solr_tricks/

> ```
> <fieldtype name="title_anchor" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="1000">
>  <analyzer>
>    <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory"
>      pattern="^(.*)$" replacement="AAAA $1" />      
>    <tokenizer class="solr.ICUTokenizerFactory"/>
>      <filter class="solr.ICUFoldingFilterFactory"/>
>      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory"
>              synonyms="syn.txt"
>              ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
>      <filter class="solr.CJKWidthFilterFactory"/>
>      <filter class="solr.CJKBigramFilterFactory"/>
>  </analyzer>
> ```